# Example of a locally compact metric space that is not sigma-compact

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory, metric-spaces, compactness

Just wondering what kind of examples would suffice for this (I’ve limited experience with topology so I’m not sure, but feels like they exist.)

And, is it possible to have a regular (Radon regular) Borel measure on it?

Edit: I wanted an example where Borel $\sigma$-algebra strictly contains set of open sets.

Comment: A discrete space of big cardinality.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio ah right. Is there a way to have a nontrivial example such that open sets and borel sets are different? Sorry about not specifying that

Comment: A disjoint union of a discrete space of big cardinality and $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @EricWofsey what would be the metric on that one though?

Comment: Use any bounded metric on $\mathbb{R}$ (say bounded by $1$), and have the points of the discrete space be distance $1$ away from everything.

Comment: @EricWofsey Thank you! I think that addresses the original question as stated (I'll ask a different question for my remaining confusions)

Comment: I don't know if it answers your question about the Radon regular measure, but in the discrete space the counting measure is regular and Radon.